# What software is helpful when designing/planning a large new personal project?

Tags: c++

I have a large and challenging C++ project that I plan to undertake, one that will take maybe 6-18 months to get to the first release. It makes sense if I'm to invest that much of my time into this, that I plan it out in detail first.

But it's also just me working on it, so the usual morass of waterfall design tools are more likely to be time wasters than time savers. Working in a solo project like I am, what software, if any more advanced than the paper and pencil, would be most helpful to me?

I know this question is somewhat subjective, but I'm counting on the community mechanic of SO to bring the best answers to the top, to get a sort of democratic answer to a question that has no concrete answer that everyone would agree on.

Comment: These kinds of questions are probably better asked on [programmers stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 6-18 months to the first release is long, try splitting the job in parts and work on the parts one at a time. Also, you could probably benefit for some prototyping to make sure that you're going in the right direction and not having to throw 3 months' work by the window when you realize you were not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing development on my own I try to keep it as simple as possible, while still having some kind of structure to it.

I think that the tools-part of the Joel test catches the most important things:

1. Do you use source control?
2. Can you make a build in one step?
3. Do you have a bug database?
4. Do you fix bugs before writing new code?

Then I'd like to add a few of my own:

1. Use automated tests and as far as possible test driven development.
2. Refactor when needed, keep the structure clean.
3. Write documentation, it is much faster to read a descriptoin than having to look through code, possibly followin several levels of function code. I often use doxygen.

Even if it's just you, you definitely want source control. Being able to track down when things changed and how they changed is invaluable in some bug fixing. Investing time in the build environment is usually worth it. You will be building this a lot. I can't keep track of bugs in my head, an excel sheet will do.

Without that basic structure in place, you can't do the refactoring when needed. Regardless of how you work with the design, refactoring those parts that didn't become good the first time is the key to sustaining a good design. If you get used to refactoring, then you won't have to think too many steps ahead, instead you can do something that works right now and then refactor it when you need to add more functionality.

Comment: +1 for mentioning invaluable use of source control while bug fixing.

Comment: And +1 for mentioning doxygen, even without the comments in the code (which wastes time more often than note), the hierarchy and collaboration diagrams are really great to have an overview.

Answer (score 1):

For a solo project, the best approach is often test-driven development in places where requirements are firm so that regression testing is automated/painless, and make good use of assertions to formalize assumptions that are made when coding.

If the tests are executed as a self-test during startup, it will highlight problems very quickly and efficiently. I have used this approach successfully when writing interpreters for various programming languages. Your mileage may vary depending on the application.

Test-driven development for solo projects makes source control almost obsolete. If your tests are good enough, then they model the requirements well enough. Fix bugs/tests before adding new functionality, and your project will meet its requirements with few outstanding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you are going to go about getting the software out the door. So think about what are you going to do about an architectural design and how you are going to drill down an fill that architecture with functionality. Once you have understood these things, the software tools that you need to use should be self-apparent.

Don't let the software drive the process; the process should drive the software.

Answer (score 0):

Big projects that work always start out as small projects that work.  Start with Hello World and keep removing bugs and adding features.  When something starts to suck, you'll know enough about it to refactor at that point.